# SSIS: How to move a project connection manager into package

Tags: deployment, ssis, connection

I have a 2012 SSIS project with many connection manager defined at project level. The project also includes many packages having a reference to these connection managers. Now I want to convert my project to a deployment model but the wizard specifies that I need to remove connection managers at project which means moving the connection managers into packages.

How can I move the project level connection managers to my package?

Comment: Are you referring to the 2012 SSIS Project deployment model? If so, why do you believe you must push them to the individual packages? If this is not 2012, then the connection managers you are referring to are design time elements and can safely be ignored

Comment: It is a 2012 project that I am trying to convert to a deployment model. To convert it I actually need to remove all project level connection managers (that is what the wizard says), which means moving project connection to packages.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need to convert the project from the Project Deployment Model to the Package Deployment Model.

[image]

From your description, you are seeing errors like this

[image]

This means you need to go into each package (sorry) and for every connection manager that indicates it's a `(project)` level one, you will right click and request that it be converted to a package level.

[image]

Comment: When I convert it, it will actually remove the connection from every other package that uses it... but that is ok because I can copy paste the connection designer object easily. Thanks.

Comment: @all: the last image explained by Bilinkc is placed below your DataFlow design.

Comment: Thanks @Amir that was a big help! IN my case, I had 4 connections and only one needed to be converted to a Package connection - so you might want to check each one to see if it needs conversion.

Answer (score 0):

You may find yourself confused by this message if you look in the project's parameters and it shows empty, and you have only package level connections. This can happen if you ever had project connections--the XML behind the package retains the deleted information. (This is in SSDT for Visual Studio 2015.)
In that case the way to correct it is to edit the XML manually.

1. **Back up the package!** The chances for errors here are high, and a single typo can render the designer unable to show you the package.
2. Right-click on the package in solution explorer and select View Code.
3. Using Find, search for locate the Project Variables opening tag. it will look like this:`<DTS:PackageParameters>`
4. Select the tag and everything down to the end tag, which will be `</DTS:PackageParameters>` and delete it.
5. Save the file and close it.
6. Return to the designer and proceed with changing the deployment model as @billinkc describes above.

That should do it.

Joey