# SSDT Set New Source as (project) Scope

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I have a new solution in SSDT where I am mapping data moving from one SQL Server to another. I will have several SSIS packages in the project, and so want to share the connections to both servers across all packages.

Here are the project level connections I have created:

[image]

When I create a new task in a Data Flow I am having trouble explicitly using the project version of my connections. I am in the prompt to add a new source, but not all my project level connections appear. I am able to add a connection, but it seems to only be scoped to the package level, which is not what I want. See conn1 is missing from the list:

[image]

**How do I explicitly use project level Connection Managers in my sources? Why don't the ones I created appear in my options as an existing source?**

Comment: FWIW, I found this question, but it is for moving from project to package, scope, and I want to move from package to project: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13472695/ssis-how-to-move-a-project-connection-manager-into-package

Answer (score 1):

it seems the connection (conn1) is not SQL Server Native Client 11.0
this source assistant Dialog retrieves only all the connections of type (SQL Server Native Client 11.0) which Microsoft recommends to use.

Regards